Ubuntu allows you to install on an SD, what exactly does that mean?
During installation it says you can install it on different things (using an SD as example) in part of the installation process. What exactly does that do? Does it just boot from the SD when booting from the computer? If so, how is that different than just making a persistent SD?

You can install Ubuntu in various random access media, for example HDD, SSD, USB stick, memory card. By that I mean create an installed Ubuntu system. You can create a live system Ubuntu in those (previously listed) media and also in a DVD disk. A persistent live system is a special case of live system, and it needs a random access medium for the persistence (a file or a partition typically in a USB stick). - I guess you mean a persistent live system in a memory card by 'persistent SD'.

I'm not sure that answers my question (tho I may have mis interpreted what you said). I know what live disks are, but in the ubuntu installer that you use when Installing from said live drive, in one of the steps it says "where would you like to install Ubuntu" or something of that sort, and it allows you to select either your internal storage, or some external storage if it's connected. My question is what does it do when you select the external storage and install it onto to there.

It does the same things when selecting external storage as when selecting internal storage, except that the target device is external instead of internal.

So like, it Installs onto and boots ubuntu from the storage? And if so, how is that different from a persistent drive? Wouldn't it be functionally the same or am I missing something?

A persistent live drive is basically a live drive, that reads the system from the media and writes it into RAM. When running it writes 'modifications' into RAM. The special feature of a persistent live drive is that is also writes and reads whatever is modified into a file or partition for persistence. I think the original reason for live systems was to be able to boot and run an operationg system from a read-only medium (floppy disk, CD or DVD disk).

Ok, so does installing it onto an external storage device just have it essentially redirect from internal storage into the external storage when attempting to boot from internal storage?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
